# Correct piping for summer water supply outdoors?

Tags: water, pipe, pump

I have a summer cottage, which is not used in winter, when the temperatures can drop to -20C (-4F) and lower.

Currently for water supply there is some existing  ~7-9m (29ft) driven well (I hope that's the correct term. I mean that there is some pipe driven into the ground, with a filter at the end of it), and some hoses which run to the pump inside kitchen and from pump to the kitchen sink.

The pump is a Calpeda CTM61 peripheral pump with turbine impeller, with a Hmin 5m thoroughput Qmax of 2,3m3/h

In autumn everything is disconnected end pump emptied so that frozen water in pipes doesn't break them.

I would like to move pump to a shed that's ~10m(30ft) away and make at least some of the piping permanent, so that I don't have to deal with hoses all the time.

To understand how I need to do it, so that it works OK, I have several questions:

1) Is diameter of pipes relevant for the pump when it sucks water from the well? I have a 1,5" diameter connectors at the well and at the pump, but I have a number of spare zinc-plated pipes that I could try use for connecting well to pump that are 1" in diameter only -- will it work with 1,5->1" adapters or must I get another pipe?

2) The same question related to the output of the pump. I would like to use piping, instead of existing flexible hose, and hope to have that piping remaining attached during winter, if I can set up pump so that the water can be drained from somewhere in the pipes.

3) What is essential for and how best to avoid air pockets for the pump intake?

Thanks in advance.